# Creat a Sparse matrix known index and value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to make a sparse matrix in python. I have the index and value of non-zero elements as a dictionary i.e.:

```
{((1,3),0.0001),(10,4),0.0212)...}
```

which means that value of element `(1,3)` is `0.0001, (10,4)` is `0.0212` etc. and the rest are zero.

I am wondering if there us any efficient method to form such a sparse matrix since the volume of data is huge. The total dimension of matrix is `2,000 X 2,000,000` while only `8,000,000` of the has value and the rest are zero.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: What do you want to use your sparse matrix for? There are many options, and the answer depends on the use you want to make of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) to represent sparse matrices. A lot of them are implemented in [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

The way you define your sparse matrix is called dictionary of keys (DOK) format, but it is not very efficient. Depending on your use, you should convert it to different format, such as CSC format for column-wise operations, CSR format for row-wise operations.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using right now will be efficient as far as time and space complexity (O(1), O(n)). Another alternative, that will be just as efficient, is a a dictionary of dictionaries. Here the first key is the x-coord, and the second key is y-coord (or vice versa). I like this because the syntax is very intuitive.

ie. to access the value at the intersection of the 3rd column and the fifth row: matrix[3][5]